# Limits in uncoutable sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, elementary-set-theory

I've been recently thinking about sequences and limits and come up with this problem.

let $A = ]0, 1[ \subset \mathbb{R}$. Define $(u_n) \subset A$ such that:

$u_0 > 0$ and for $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, u_{n+1} > u_n $.

> Can we say that $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} u_n = 1$ ?

Sorry if this sounds stupid, just been thinking about for a while now and need a confirmation. I am not sure because $\#\mathbb{N} < \#\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Of course not. The limit could be any number between $0$ and $1$, provided the sequence is bounded. Consider $(1/2)-1/(n+2)$.

Comment: Did you mean $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} u_n = 1$

Comment: Note that $(u_n)\subseteq A$ and $u_0=0$ are mutually exclusive, because $0\notin A$.

Comment: @Arthur, yeah sorry, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is a strictly increasing sequence in an interval. Such a sequence, being increasing and bounded from above in $\Bbb{R}$, a complete ordered metric space, must have a limit. That limit can be any number at all in the interval, though. Say you want a limit of $a<1$, just approach it like [Zeno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes): At each step, cross half of the remaining distance. Your sequence will be precisely $(\frac{a}2,\frac{3a}4,\frac{7a}8,\ldots)$.

(If you want to include $0$ as the first term of the sequence, you should probably start, as suggested in a comment, by setting $A=[0,1)$.)

Answer (score 3):

No, we can't. Take, for instance, the sequence $u_n=\frac12-\frac1{n+3}$.